# Matching Array values in mule 4 using dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am trying to match the specific value from input payload using dataweave.

Input:

```
{
    "drives": [{
        "id": "0AEzOyzyCb7Uk9PVA",
        "name": "SFJob-2020-10"
    }, {
        "id": "0AMEHi1wsq-8FUk9PVA",
        "name": "SFJobs-2020-11"
    } ],
    "nextPageToken": "~!!~AI9FV7RV4uSXy20zpCBTP2LFWCXS0c"
},
{
    "drives": [{
        "id": "0AEz3mOyzyCb7Uk9PVA",
        "name": "Dev2020-10"
    }, {
        "id": "0AMEHi1wsq-8FUk9PVA",
        "name": "Dev2020-11"
    }],
"nextPageToken": "~!!~AI9P2LFWCXS0c"
}
```

how can i check whether value "Dev2020-10" is present or not.

i am using below code giving me error.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.drives filter ((item, index) -> item.name == 'Dev2020-10')
```

Expected output:

[
{

```
"id": "0AEz3mOyzyCb7Uk9PVA",
"name": "Dev2020-10"
```

}
]

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

First, the input is not valid. I assume that it is supposed to be a JSON array so I enclosed into brackets: `[ {..},{..} ]`.

After that you will notice that the filter is expecting a single object, but because it is an array you need to map it first. To return a single array I used a flatMap():

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload flatMap $.drives filter ((item, index) -> item.name == 'Dev2020-10')
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "0AEz3mOyzyCb7Uk9PVA",
    "name": "Dev2020-10"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be thought of two steps:

1. Merge all the drives together to get a single array of objects `flatten(inputArray.drives)`
2. Filter the new array of objects based on the search criteria `filter ((item, index) -> item.name == "Dev2020-11")`

The solution will be this :

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var inputArray = [
    {
    "drives": [{
        "id": "0AEzOyzyCb7Uk9PVA",
        "name": "SFJob-2020-10"
    }, {
        "id": "0AMEHi1wsq-8FUk9PVA",
        "name": "SFJobs-2020-11"
    } ],
    "nextPageToken": "~!!~AI9FV7RV4uSXy20zpCBTP2LFWCXS0c"
    },
    {
    "drives": [{
        "id": "0AEz3mOyzyCb7Uk9PVA",
        "name": "Dev2020-10"
    }, {
        "id": "0AMEHi1wsq-8FUk9PVA",
        "name": "Dev2020-11"
    }],
"nextPageToken": "~!!~AI9P2LFWCXS0c"
    }
]
---
flatten(inputArray.drives) filter ((item, index) -> item.name == "Dev2020-11")
```

To learn more about flatten method, refer the documentation : [mule 4 doc](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-flatten)